# CommentThreads & maxResults parameter not working correctly on Youtube API v3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The [commentThreads](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) endpoint with videoId is experiencing multiple issues (YouTube API v3).

If you use the parameter maxResults=100, it returns only 20 (the default) items. It seems that the endpoint is currently not using that parameter, issues started today.

Also not all comments in total seems to be returning by this endpoint for paginated requests for multiple issues. I assume this is related, but could be also another issue.

Example request: [https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&maxResults=100&videoId=LkpZ3qKLrsQ&key={api-key}](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&maxResults=100&videoId=LkpZ3qKLrsQ&key=%7Bapi-key%7D)

Expected comments (data.items) in response: 77
Actually comments (data.items): 20 (the default maxResults) with a nextPageToken provided

For the other issue you can use the same request with videoId wqW5vgARg4k and following the pagination by adding pageToken={nextPageToken from previous request}.
It is only returning 292 (484 with replies) comments, but should return 22596 comments.

**Update** Issue fixed by YouTube Team on Nov 14, 2023

Comment: Also experiencing this. I can request fewer than 20 results, but asking for anything more than 20 only returns 20 results. This is a very serious issue since we are now spending 500% as much quota to get the same number of comments, and I'm curious why youtube hasn't addressed or fixed this yet.

Comment: Yes same, quotas are reached 5 times faster. In some cases it returns 21 results for the first page. Found out that maxResults=100 working with param order=relevance and is returning 100 results. Only issue is that it is not returning all comments with videos with many comments.

Seems no way to report, other then stackoverflow. Not sure if google issue tracker is actively used.

Comment: Yes as @koen mentioned sometimes it returns 20 and in some scenarios it returns 21 but not more than that, is anyone found alternate way for this?

Comment: I still see this issue and raised issue in issue tracker below https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/309981763